# Is there a way to store a variable from program memory to hardisk retaining functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to save a variable containing an array of objects of a class in NodeJS to a file so that I can reuse it from there instead of having to reobtain it like so

```
const chatAPI = require("some_module");
const client = new chatAPI.Client("Auth-Key");
var channels = client.channels();
//Now channels is something I would like to use later on 

//Say
channels.forEach(channel => {channel.send("Hello")});
```

Is there any way I can save the channels variable to a file so I can load it again into program memory at a later run and use it as I have without having to create a new client and fetch the data.

To elaborate it would be the same as if I let this program run for a while with a blocking loop, and later use the variable, in that case, I would not have to reparse or reconstruct the data anyhow.

Comment: You can save data in a file as data is independent, you can't save objects as object has methods and references to memory which cannot be saved and lost upon program exit. You can though strip data from object and save it and later initialize the object from that data if the object supports it.

Comment: What is the reason behind not wanting to leave the program running?

Comment: You may find the cryo library at https://github.com/hunterloftis/cryo useful.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways of doing this, e.g.

```
let a = {foo: "bar" };
console.log("a", a);

fs.writeFileSync("./saved_data.json", JSON.stringify(a));

let b = require("./saved_data.json");
console.log("b", b);
```

You can also:

```
let b = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./saved_data.json"));
console.log("b", b);
```

Now you can only save the *data* not the methods!

If you want to retain an *object* I would use a global variable to store this:

```
let globalObject = null;

someMethod.get((obj) => {
    // Save this for later use
    globalObject = obj;
})

// Later on
if (globalObject) {
    globalObject.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to store that global variable in a file, and not leave the program running

Comment: So you can do that if the variable can be converted to JSON. If the object contains methods / functions you can't do this easily. It's _possible_ but I don't think it's really a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I used these two functions in my projects,
it stores the data in the default AppData folder of the operating system:

```
const {
  app
} = remote
const fs = require('fs')

function get_option(file, callback) {
  fs.readFile(
    app.getPath('userData') + '\\user_data' + '\\' + file, 'utf8',
    function (err, data) {
      callback(err, data)
    }
  )
}

function set_option(file, data) {
  if (data) {
    fs.writeFileSync(
      app.getPath('userData') + '\\user_data' + '\\' + file, data
    )
  } else {
    fs.unlink(
      app.getPath('userData') + '\\user_data' + '\\' + file,
      function (err) {}
    )
  }
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
set_option(
  'data.json',
  JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
)

get_option('data.json', function (err, data) {
  if (!err && data) {
    let jsonObject = JSON.parse(data)
    // Do something ..
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

from my experience, for a small scale project, best option is to go with SQLite database which can be used without any database engine and the whole database itself would just be one easily movable file. this also supports (generally) standard sql queries to insert, update, select.
this needs only one "require" in node.js and same functions can be used on php, android, and almost any other platform with minimal effort.

this is sample insert and select

```
  //-- sqlite3 db --//
  ////////////////////
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
function AddChatlogToDB(from,to,content){
      // open the database
      let db = new sqlite3.Database('./chatLog.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return false;
        }
            /////INSERT INTO TABLE
        db.run("INSERT INTO chatLogs (cl_time,cl_from,cl_to,cl_content) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
            [Date.now(),from,to,content]);

        db.close((err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
          }
          //console.log('Close the database connection.');
         return true;
        });

        console.log("chatlog: ", from,to,content);
      });
}


function getLast20ChatLogs(uid, callback){
  let db = new sqlite3.Database('./chatLog.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    }


    let sql = 'Select * from chatLogs WHERE cl_to IS NULL  ORDER BY cl_time DESC limit 20;'
    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      if(callback) callback(rows);
    });

    db.close((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
    });

  });
}
```